# Problemas con mi app de android studio API REST GET

Tags: android-studio, rest, get, base64, retrofit

tengo un error con mi app que utiliza método GET.

al ejecutarla no abre.

en mi postman ejecuto con su usuario, contraseña y parametros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo en mi mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private TextView textViewResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_Resul);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

        String userName ="sbasilico";
        String password ="xxxxxx";
        String base = userName + ":" + password;

        String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(base.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        //Call<Datareq>call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getDatareqs(80003, authHeader);
        Call<Map<String,Datareq>>call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getDatareqs(80003, authHeader, "JSESSIONID=fYAV2KfouyICoHiKGuJ5n_-Q0kQOc-KNl6HmFk9Ce8K5JQtuMa7A!-530853743", "application/json;charset=UTF-8" );

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, Datareq>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Map<String, Datareq>> call, Response<Map<String, Datareq>> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    textViewResult.setText("code: "+ response.code());
                    return;
                }

                List<Datareq> datareqs = (List<Datareq>) response.body();

                for (Datareq datareq : datareqs) {
                    String content = "";
                    content += "tableId: " + datareq.getTableId() + "\n";
                    content += "rowset: " + datareq.getRecords() + "\n";
                    content += "records: " + datareq.getRecords() + "\n";
                    content += "moreRecords: " + datareq.getMoreRecords() + "\n";

                    textViewResult.append(content);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Map<String, Datareq>> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

mi interface donde tengo mi método GET

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {




@GET("jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011A_ORCH")

Call<Map<String,Datareq>>getDatareqs(@Query("Cliente") double cliente,
                                     @Header("Authorization")String authHeader,
                                     @Header("Cookie") String cookie,
                                     @Header ("Content-Type") String content
);
```

acá estan los datos que quiero que aparezcan mi app

```
public class Datareq {

@SerializedName("tableId")
private String tableId;

//se creó una clase para llamar a los atributos de este objeto en "MoreRowsets"
@SerializedName("rowset")
private List<MoreRowsets> rowsets;

@SerializedName("records")
private Integer records;


@SerializedName("moreRecords")
private Boolean moreRecords;

//constructors

public Datareq(String tableId, List<MoreRowsets> rowsets, Integer records, Boolean moreRecords) {
    this.tableId = tableId;
    this.rowsets = rowsets;
    this.records = records;
    this.moreRecords = moreRecords;
}

//getters y setters
public String getTableId() {
    return tableId;
}

public void setTableId(String tableId) {
    this.tableId = tableId;
}

public List<MoreRowsets> getRowsets() {
    return rowsets;
}

public void setRowsets(List<MoreRowsets> rowsets) {
    this.rowsets = rowsets;
}

public Integer getRecords() {
    return records;
}

public void setRecords(Integer records) {
    this.records = records;
}

public Boolean getMoreRecords() {
    return moreRecords;
}

public void setMoreRecords(Boolean moreRecords) {
    this.moreRecords = moreRecords;
}
```

}

la llamada de rowset

```
public class MoreRowsets {

@SerializedName("NRO_INTERNO")
private double nroInterno;

@SerializedName("TIPO_INTERNO")
private String tipoInterno;

@SerializedName("FECHA_FACTURA")
private Date fechaFactura;

@SerializedName("MONTO")
private double monto;

@SerializedName("FECHA_VENCIMIENTO")
private Date fechaVencimiento;

@SerializedName("NRO_LEGAL")
private double nroLegal;


//getters

public double getNroInterno() {
    return nroInterno;
}

public String getTipoInterno() {
    return tipoInterno;
}

public Date getFechaFactura() {
    return fechaFactura;
}

public double getMonto() {
    return monto;
}

public Date getFechaVencimiento() {
    return fechaVencimiento;
}

public double getNroLegal() {
    return nroLegal;
}


//constructors


public MoreRowsets(double nroInterno, String tipoInterno, Date fechaFactura, double monto, Date fechaVencimiento, double nroLegal) {
    this.nroInterno = nroInterno;
    this.tipoInterno = tipoInterno;
    this.fechaFactura = fechaFactura;
    this.monto = monto;
    this.fechaVencimiento = fechaVencimiento;
    this.nroLegal = nroLegal;
}
```

en conclusión, no sé cómo continuarla. no me aparece nada en el debug especifico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando extiendo en el postman el "rowset" aparecen mas datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay algo que me este saltando? ¿debo agregar mas código? ¿sacar? mi objetivo es recuperar en un textView o en otro lado lo que aparece en el postman.

desde ya muchas gracias! si necesito poner algo mas como el manifest o properties, lo haré.